# Error Exception while sending the check payment request through Spree API in iOS application

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, json, spree

Currently I'm developing an e-commerce iOS application using Spree. Right now I'm able to send order & checkout the process through the Spree API but got stuck while sending the payment options.

Here, their are 2 payment options:

1. Credit Card (payment_method_id = 1)
2. Check       (payment_method_id = 2)

According to Spree API Documentation, https://guides.spreecommerce.com/api/checkouts.html#confirm

> To advance to the next state, confirm, the order will need to have a
>   payment. You can create a payment by passing in parameters such as
>   this:
>
> ```
> {   "order": {
>     "payments_attributes": [
>       {
>         "payment_method_id": "1"
>       }
>     ]   },   "payment_source": {
>     "1": {
>       "number": "4111111111111111",
>       "month": "1",
>       "year": "2017",
>       "verification_value": "123",
>       "name": "John Smith"
>     }   } }
> ```
>
> The numbered key in the payment_source hash directly corresponds to
>   the **payment_method_id** attribute within the **payment_attributes** key.

**UPDATE**

And when I send this json for payment checkout

```
{ order: { "payment_attributes": [ { "payment_method_id": 2 } ], "state": "payment", "use_existing_card": "no" } }
```

I get this error exception response on the logs and also in background, SHOCKINGLY the order state gets changed to `complete` state, don't know how but the payment gets complete and JSON responses I get this undefined method error

```
2015-10-09T13:29:59.580871+00:00 app[web.1]: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
2015-10-09T13:29:59.586799+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 857ms (Views: 4.0ms | ActiveRecord: 334.6ms)
2015-10-09T13:29:59.523283+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "spree_payments".* FROM "spree_payments" WHERE "spree_payments"."order_id" = $1 AND ("spree_payments"."state" NOT IN ('failed', 'invalid'))  ORDER BY spree_payments.created_at  [["order_id", 364]]
2015-10-09T13:29:59.550332+00:00 app[web.1]:   SQL (3.3ms)  UPDATE "spree_orders" SET "payment_state" = $1, "shipment_state" = $2, "updated_at" = $3 WHERE "spree_orders"."id" = $4  [["payment_state", "balance_due"], ["shipment_state", "pending"], ["updated_at", "2015-10-09 13:29:59.538550"], ["id", 364]]
2015-10-09T13:29:59.559930+00:00 app[web.1]:    (1.5ms)  BEGIN
2015-10-09T13:29:59.568004+00:00 app[web.1]:    (1.8ms)  COMMIT
2015-10-09T13:29:59.571496+00:00 app[web.1]: [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [f07d385a-feeb-4df3-86e9-75fde134917c] Performing ActionMailer::DeliveryJob from Inline(mailers) with arguments: "Spree::OrderMailer", "confirm_email", "deliver_now", 364
2015-10-09T13:29:59.578783+00:00 app[web.1]: [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [f07d385a-feeb-4df3-86e9-75fde134917c] 
2015-10-09T13:29:59.578786+00:00 app[web.1]: Spree::OrderMailer#confirm_email: processed outbound mail in 3.4ms
2015-10-09T13:29:59.580392+00:00 app[web.1]: [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [f07d385a-feeb-4df3-86e9-75fde134917c] Performed ActionMailer::DeliveryJob from Inline(mailers) in 5.56ms
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581859+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bundler/gems/spree-multi-domain-93fc80961817/app/mailers/spree/order_mailer.rb:6:in `confirm_email'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581862+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581864+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581865+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581867+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581868+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581869+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581871+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581872+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581874+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.4/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:596:in `block in process'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581875+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581877+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581878+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581879+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.4/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:593:in `process'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581880+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.4/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:584:in `initialize'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581881+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.4/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:25:in `new'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581882+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.4/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:25:in `__getobj__'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581884+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.4/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:34:in `message'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581885+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.4/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:85:in `deliver_now'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581886+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.4/lib/action_mailer/delivery_job.rb:10:in `perform'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581887+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.4/lib/active_job/execution.rb:32:in `block in perform_now'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581888+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581890+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581891+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581892+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581893+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581895+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:498:in `block (2 levels) in around'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581896+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:343:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581897+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:343:in `block (2 levels) in simple'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581899+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n.rb:257:in `with_locale'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581900+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.4/lib/active_job/translation.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Translation>'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581901+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:441:in `instance_exec'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581903+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:441:in `block in make_lambda'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581904+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:342:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581905+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:342:in `block in simple'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581907+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:497:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581908+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:497:in `block in around'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581913+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581914+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581915+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:498:in `block (2 levels) in around'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581916+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:343:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581918+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:343:in `block (2 levels) in simple'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581919+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.4/lib/active_job/logging.rb:23:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581921+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.4/lib/active_job/logging.rb:23:in `block (4 levels) in <module:Logging>'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581922+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581923+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581925+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581926+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.4/lib/active_job/logging.rb:22:in `block (3 levels) in <module:Logging>'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581927+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.4/lib/active_job/logging.rb:43:in `block in tag_logger'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581929+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581930+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581931+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581933+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.4/lib/active_job/logging.rb:43:in `tag_logger'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581934+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.4/lib/active_job/logging.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Logging>'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581936+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:441:in `instance_exec'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581937+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:441:in `block in make_lambda'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581938+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:342:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581940+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:342:in `block in simple'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581941+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:497:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581942+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:497:in `block in around'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581943+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581944+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581946+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581947+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_perform_callbacks'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581948+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581949+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.4/lib/active_job/execution.rb:31:in `perform_now'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581951+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.4/lib/active_job/execution.rb:21:in `execute'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581952+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.4/lib/active_job/queue_adapters/inline_adapter.rb:14:in `enqueue'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581953+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.4/lib/active_job/enqueuing.rb:71:in `block in enqueue'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581954+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581955+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581956+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581957+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581959+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581963+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:498:in `block (2 levels) in around'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581964+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:343:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581965+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:343:in `block (2 levels) in simple'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581967+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.4/lib/active_job/logging.rb:14:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581968+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.4/lib/active_job/logging.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in <module:Logging>'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581969+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.4/lib/active_job/logging.rb:43:in `block in tag_logger'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581971+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581972+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581973+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581974+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.4/lib/active_job/logging.rb:43:in `tag_logger'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581976+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.4/lib/active_job/logging.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Logging>'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581977+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:441:in `instance_exec'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581978+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:441:in `block in make_lambda'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581980+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:342:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581981+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:342:in `block in simple'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581987+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:497:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581988+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:497:in `block in around'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581990+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581991+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581992+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581994+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_enqueue_callbacks'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581995+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581996+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.4/lib/active_job/enqueuing.rb:67:in `enqueue'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581998+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.4/lib/active_job/configured_job.rb:13:in `perform_later'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581999+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.4/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:112:in `enqueue_delivery'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582001+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.4/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:68:in `deliver_later'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582002+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/spree_core-3.0.4/app/models/spree/order.rb:359:in `deliver_order_confirmation_email'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582003+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/spree_core-3.0.4/app/models/spree/order.rb:347:in `finalize!'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582005+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/eval_helpers.rb:58:in `evaluate_method'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582006+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/callback.rb:192:in `block in run_methods'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582007+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/callback.rb:191:in `each'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582008+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/callback.rb:191:in `run_methods'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582010+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/callback.rb:159:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582011+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/transition.rb:394:in `block (2 levels) in after'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582012+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/transition.rb:394:in `each'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582013+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/transition.rb:394:in `block in after'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582014+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/transition.rb:392:in `catch'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582018+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/transition.rb:392:in `after'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582103+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582104+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582106+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582107+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582108+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582109+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582113+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582114+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582116+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582117+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582118+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582119+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582120+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582121+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582123+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582124+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582125+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582126+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582127+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582128+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582130+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582131+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582132+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582133+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582135+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582136+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582137+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582138+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.583078+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered text template (0.0ms)
```

Comment: This is helpful to you: https://guides.spreecommerce.com/api/payments.html#new

Comment: please check the edit of the question

Comment: now payment done for this order? and I think, you have to call the confirm api as well.

Comment: Try sending this JSON for the check payment type: `{
  order: {
    "payment_attributes": [
      {
        "payment_method_id": 2
      }
    ]
    }
}
` Also, you need to post this to: `/api/checkouts/<order_number>?order_token=<order_token>`

Comment: Also, this link helped me a lot with the checkout process: https://github.com/radar/spree_api_examples/blob/master/examples/checkout/walkthrough.rb .Here is my app: https://goo.gl/wp1klB

Comment: @SanadLiaquat Please look at the update section of the question. I have tried your suggestion but facing some other issues